# How to fill a struct with data from a file?

Tags: c, file, struct

So i have this assignment where i have to read a file which contains  first/last names as well as  ids and grades of numerous students like this "fist last id grade" find the average grade,the student with the best grade etc. and then write the results in another file using structs.So my question is,how can i pass the data of each line in the struct ? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ... here is a link to an article which described what is considered good content in a question ... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Assuming that each line of input file contains a data record and members of data record are separated by space character a simple solution could be: use `getline()` to read file line by line. For each line use either `sscanf()` to assign data to members of struct or split line into tokens using `strtok()` and assign tokens to according members of struct. Tokens for `id` and `grade` must be converted to right data type. Add checks for record size, data validity etc. . Don't forget to free memory allocated by `getline()`.